# How to remove a blade safely from a bandsaw?

Tags: band-saw

It is the time that I need to remove the blade since it is dull now, is there any tip or trick to remove the bandsaw blade safely? I use a WEN 14' type model.

Answer (score 4):

1. grab a set of gloves and eye protection and put them on.
2. unplug the bandsaw
3. open the enclosure and remove the blade insert in the table. Make sure the slot in the table is clear and ready for the blade to come through.
4. find the tension knob and turn to release all the blade tension until the blade sits loosely on the upper wheel
5. now you can remove the blade from the wheels and rotate the blade to exit the slot in the table. [Store the blade safely.](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/q/41/20)
6. follow steps in reverse to put the new blade on the wheel making sure that the teeth are pointing down.
7. before closing the enclosure turn the wheels by hand to make sure the blade tracks properly on the wheels.

Comment: Good Answer, shame it's on a question posed by a spammer :-(